# I can't get label=sprintf to force my labels to show 2 decimal places

Tags: r, ggplot2, decimal, geom-col

I have the following dataframe:

```
Q <- data.frame("PERC" = c(1.1, 2.1, 8.3, 7.0, 9.8, 3.1, 4.1, 11.3,
                           9.0, 3.0, 4.0, 11.0, 1.1, 2.1, 8.3, 7.0,
                           9.0, 3.0, 8.3, 7.0),
           "Corp" = c("Aus", "China" ,"Aus", "China", "Aus", "China", 
                      "Aus", "China", "Aus", "China" ,"Aus", "China",
                      "Aus", "China" ,"Aus", "China", 
                      "Aus", "China" ,"Aus", "China"),
           "Journal" = c("O", "O", "G", "G", "O", "O", "G", "G",
                         "O", "O", "G", "G", "O", "O", "G", "G", 
                         "O", "O", "G", "G"),
           "Year" = c("2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", 
                      "2015", "2015", "2015",
                      "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016",
                      "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017",
                      "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018"),
           "lbl" = c(NA, "n = 60", NA, "n = 62", NA, "n = 70",
                     NA, "n = 93", NA, "n = 78", NA, "n = 26",
                     NA, "n = 2010", NA, "n = 30", 
                     NA, "n = 2014", NA, "n = 99"))
```

And when I try to make the following plot, even though I am using label=sprintf in the `aes`, I can't get the figure to show the ".0" such as *11.0*, *3.0* or *7.0* it only shows *11*, *3*, *7*. Could somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

```
ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(Year, PERC, label=sprintf("%0.2f", round(PERC, digits = 2)),
                               fill = Corp))+
  geom_col(position = "stack", alpha = 1, width = 0.9)+
  facet_wrap(~Journal)+
  geom_text(aes(label=PERC), colour = "Black", 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3.5)+
  xlab("\nPublished Year") + 
  ylab("Measured amount/Total amount (%)\n")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 13, by = 1), expand = c(0.1, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#0072B2", "#E69F00","#0072B2"),
                    labels = c("Australia",
                               "China"))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank())+
  geom_text(aes(label = lbl), y = -0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels are overwritten in `geom_text` again when you have defined them in `aes` already. Try :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(Year, PERC, 
       label=sprintf("%0.2f", round(PERC, digits = 2)),
                               fill = Corp))+
  geom_col(position = "stack", alpha = 1, width = 0.9)+
  facet_wrap(~Journal)+
  geom_text(colour = "Black", 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3.5)+
  xlab("\nPublished Year") + 
  ylab("Measured amount/Total amount (%)\n")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 13, by = 1), expand = c(0.1, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#0072B2", "#E69F00","#0072B2"),
                    labels = c("Australia",
                               "China"))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank())+
  geom_text(aes(label = lbl), y = -0.5)
```

[image]